# Josh Smith MVVM Demo app

Tags: c#, mvvm, datatemplate

In **MainWindow** we have:

```
 <HeaderedContentControl 
          Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
          Header="Workspaces"
          Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"
          />
```

In the **resources**:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <TabControl 
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
      Margin="4"
      />
  </DataTemplate>
```

And in the **article** says:

> A typed DataTemplate does not have an x:Key value assigned to it, but
>   it does have its DataType property set to an instance of the Type
>   class. **If WPF tries to render one of your ViewModel objects, it will
>   check to see if the resource system has a typed DataTemplate in scope
>   whose DataType is the same as (or a base class of) the type of your
>   ViewModel object**. If it finds one, it uses that template to render the
>   ViewModel object referenced by the tab item's Content property.

My **question** is:

How does the template know that the type is a collection of workspaces (WorkspaceViewModel)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't need to, in the code you've posted.  In your sample, you have given a strict value to your content template: you've explicitly used `{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}`, and so a resource with the key of `"WorkspacesTemplate` is looked up.

Because you've explicitly set the template, it doesn't matter what the intended type is: it'll try to display any object in your `Content` using the template you've set - with varying degrees of success if you use a type that doesn't match!

In the alternate method you mention - with a "typed DataTemplate", you would declare your datatemplate with `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:WorkSpace}" />`.  Note that there is no `x:Key` (and also that I've assumed you have a namespace `l` mapped to your local code).  What happens here is that WPF automatically sets the key of your resource to the `DataType` (important to note: a resource key doesn't have to be a string!).

Then, when you declare your `HeaderedContentControl`, you can leave out setting the `ContentTemplate`.  At runtime, when the control is rendered, WPF will check the type of the `Content` object and find that it is `WorkSpace`, and it'll then look up a resource with `x:Key="{x:Type l:WorkSpace}"` - which will match your typed template.

This is a useful way of making consistent representations of data throughout your application, since a typed `DataTemplate` will be used automatically by any content-presenting control throughout your application.

Answer (score 4):

WPF doesn't really care about the concrete type, it's just need to be some IEnumerable of something, WPF uses the type descriptor to know what the ui binding with.

Comment: In some definitions of template I've seen this (in the same project):  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}"> What is that TargetType?

Comment: When you add target type you don't have to specify the template in the items control, wpf will automatically search for a template with the relvant target type, It's just another option. Best practice is to use both.